# Serial port issue on writing

Tags: uwp, serial-port, modbus

I'm tring to talk/listen every 10 seconds to a serial port(modbus rsu 485). (UWP project)

I followed the official example proposed by Microsoft and adapted to my personal case.

The issue I'm facing is that randomly the WriteAsync() task writes the message two times consequently... for example it should write "hello" instead it writes "hellohello" generating an Unhandled Exception in 'System.Exception' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll ...

here is the rilevant code:

```
public async Task WriteAsync()
    {
        DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(PortaSeriale.OutputStream);

        string Funzione03 = "0x01 0x03 0x80 0x01 0x00 0x04 0x3C 0x09";

        byte[] bytes = Funzione03.Split(' ').Select(item => Convert.ToByte(item, 16)).ToArray();

        if (dataWriter != null)
        {
            dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync().AsTask();
            dataWriter.DetachStream();                
            dataWriter = null;                
        }
    }
```

And here is the Read function

```
public async Task<string> ReadAsync(uint ReadBufferLength)
    {
        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;
        byte[] ByteLettura = null;           
        dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;          

        loadAsyncTask = dataReader.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask();

        UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask; //base 32bit

        if (bytesRead > 0) //se leggi byte, convertili in Hexadecimal
        {

            ByteLettura = dataReader.ReadBuffer(bytesRead).ToArray();
            string HexMessage = string.Join("-", ByteLettura.Select(item => item.ToString("X2")));

            return HexMessage;}
        return $""; 
    }
```

The timer is set in MainPage and ticks every 10 seconds. If it is necessary I'll post its code.

I don't know how to deal with this issue... any suggestion ?

thx!

Comment: How do you specify ReadBufferLength?

Comment: On main page, the function is called as Ricevuto = await modBus.ReadAsync(1024); maybe 1024 is the problem?

Comment: Could you share your code sample?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT  Here I have upload a [gists](https://gist.github.com/NommySkies/50a8255bf48b4ede63c47918eed68336)

Comment: nothing found? :(